# Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`MessageController`)

Tags: reactjs, components, antd, message, setstate

we need help. I get these errors when calling a component that uses a message from antd. How to fix it? Or maybe it is possible to rewrite this code so that this error disappears, but the functionality remains the same (a message was displayed when an error occurred)

App component:

```
const App = () => {
  const { isShowMessage, message } = useSelector((state) => state.appMessage);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          {isShowMessage && message && <MessageController messageData={message} />}

          <Switch>
              <Redirect exact from={routeNames.main} to={routeNames.events} />
              {privateRoutes.map((route) => (
                <Route key={route.path} {...route} />
              ))}
             <Redirect push to={routeNames.events} />
          </Switch>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Switch>
          {publicRoutes.map((route) => (
            <Route key={route.path} {...route} />
          ))}
          <Redirect push to={routeNames.login} />
        </Switch>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Controller component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { message } from 'antd';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { messageAction } from '../../store/message';

const MessageController = ({ messageData }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { text, type } = messageData;

  dispatch(messageAction.hideMessage());
  return message[type](text, { maxCount: 1, duration: 2 });
};

export default MessageController;
```

[error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsyIl.png) - this is screenshot with console error

Comment: I would move the `useSelector` inside `MessageController`, since the the data is only needed there. You also have a dispatch that runs every time MessageController renders, which may not be what you intended? Also check the return value from MessageController, I'm not sure what you currently have is valid as a return value of a React component.

Comment: MessageController return "function", i check it with typeof

Comment: See the bottom error message in your picture? Change the return type to something that can be rendered. I'm also pretty sure you don't want to dispatch hideMessage unconditionally, I think that's causing you problems right now. Try putting the dispatch into a useEffect, so that it doesn't interfere with rendering the component.
`
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(messageAction.hideMessage());
}, [dispatch])
`